# Slim Framework 404 instead of a correct answer

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, slim, restful-architecture

I want to create a RESTful service using the Slim framework and on my localhost (xampp) everything works as expected.

I have several paths like `'/'`, `'/articles'`, `'/articles/id/{id}'`, etc..

However, only `'/'` ( http://mydomain.de/api ) brings the correct answer when I upload my code to the server and the other paths will only bring a 404 error (the one of the server, not the one Slim throws). My .htaccess in `/TEST/api` is:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /TEST/api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

With the second line uncommented I get the same result. Is there something I am missing? How can I find out wether my .htaccess-settings are used or not?

Comment: I would first check AllowOverride All in Apache conf file. Error makes me think of that.

Comment: Additionally I use following instead: RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Comment: I don't have direct access to the conf file. There is only a web backend where I can change some settings.

Comment: The question is confusing. What is the url for your api?  http://mydomain.de/api  or  http://mydomain.de/TEST/api? In any case the problem is your rewrite rules are not working.  Most likely smozgurs suggestion about AllowOverride All.

Comment: The url mydomain.de is mapped to to the folder /TEST on the server, so mydomain.de/api will be mapped to /TEST/api where i have the htaccess file.

Comment: Then the correct base is: RewriteBase /api/

Comment: Check to see if rewrite is allowed, go to the api location directly and find out if index.php is called. Like http://domain.com/api/something. According to htaccess it should call index.php. If not then you need allowoverride all for the directory. Also, Mika's base suggestion is also correct according to root mapping.

Comment: Yes, with Mika's RewriteBase every it works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That leads to the same result.

Comment: have you mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: I don't have direct access to the httpd.conf but the support said "in theory setting the option SymLinksIfOwnerMatch to "On" also enable mod_rewrite". But he said, that I could do some extra configurations via a php.ini. Do you know how?

Comment: Mod_rewrite has nothning to do with php settings. Change the base as Mika suggested. It should help.